# Solve limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \sin (x)}{(x \sin (x))^{3/2}}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Hi I must  solve the next limit $\infty -  $\infty$ usibg L'Hopital and Taylor series.

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x -  \sin (x)}{(x \sin (x))^{3/2} }$

I tried to eliminate the root with multiplying by 
$1 = \frac{(x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{2}})}{(x \sin (x))^{\frac{1}{2}}} $

Byt whe I tried to apply L'Hopital the Sin function is very problematic

Answer (score 4):

You have with Taylor series around $0$ : $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x -  \sin (x)}{(x \sin (x))^{3/2} }=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x -  x + \frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{(x (x+o(x))^{3/2} }=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{x^3 +o(x^3) }= \frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x\to 0$ we have $(\sin x)^{3/2}\sim x^{3/2}$ and so
$$
\frac{x-\sin x}{(x\sin x)^{3/2}}\sim \frac{\frac{x^3}{3!}}{x^{3/2}( x)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{6}
$$

Comment: You forgot $x$ in the denominator.. It seems there's a minimum character limit for edits though

Answer (score 2):

In products/quotients, you can trade $\sin(x)$ for $x$ as their ratio tends to $1$.

Then by L'Hospital and a well-known limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{3x^2}=-\frac16.$$

Note that you may not substitute $\sin(x)$ for $x$ in the numerator as there is a subtraction, not a product.

---

For the final limit,

$$\lim_{2x\to0}\frac{\cos(2x)-1}{(2x)^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2\sin^2(x)}{4x^2}=-\frac12\cdot1^2.$$